# Customize \section

Tags: sectioning, counters

I have a document, where I want typical code: "Problem # n" to be printed in every section. I made this code, which is working. How can I get rid of `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}` and `\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\begin{center}\Large{\bf{Problem \# \arabic{secnumdepth}}}\end{center}
\addtocounter{secnumdepth}{1}}
\begin{document}
\section{}
text
\section{}
text
\section{}
text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Surely `secnumdepth` is *not* the counter to use here.

Comment: you might consider treating this as a theorem-class environment where you can relatively freely define the heading text and the counter is supplied automatically.  you'd want to use a theorem package that provides several different styles (unlike the `article` default), since you most likely don't want the text in italic.

Comment: Please note that neither `\Large` nor `\bf` are commands that take an argument. Thus, it's not necessary to encase the subsequent material in braces. The scope of these two commands will end automatically when the `\end{center}` instruction is encountered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{1}`, but still have to increase the counter every time:

```
\documentclass{article}
\renewcommand{\section}[1]{\addtocounter{section}{1}\begin{center}\Large{\bf{Problem \# \arabic{section}}}\end{center}}
\begin{document}
\section{}
text
\section{}
text
\section{}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: A potentially serious issue with your proposed solution (as well as the OP's originally-proposed method...) is that a "section header" line could end up stranded as the last item on a page -- an offense against good typography. LaTeX's ordinary sectioning commands provide a lot of code to avoid just such outcomes.

Comment: Yes, I must manually avoid it.

Answer (score 6):

The counter `secnumdepth` controls the level up to which sectional units will be numbered, so it doen't make much sense to use this counter to number your structure.

One possibility using the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\Large\bfseries\filcenter}{Problem \# \thesection}
  {0em}{}

\begin{document}
\section{}
text
\section{}
text
\section{}
text
\end{document}
```

Perhaps you could consider defining a dedicated command/environmet for this instead of (ab)using `\section`?

Here's a better option, using a theorem-like structure defined with the help of the `amsthm` package; in this way, the counter is provided and increased automatically (feel free to make the adjustments that best suit your needs):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\newtheoremstyle{mystyle}
  {\topsep}{\topsep}{\normalfont}{}{\Large\bfseries}{\newline}{0em}
  {\hfil\thmname{#1 \#}\thmnumber{ #2}\thmnote{#3}\hfil}
\theoremstyle{mystyle}
\newtheorem{prob}{Problem}

\begin{document}

\begin{prob}
text
\end{prob}

\begin{prob}
text
\end{prob}

\end{document}
```

As a side note, `\bf` is an obsolete command (only provided for compatibility); you should use `\bfseries` instead; additionally `\bf` and `\bfseries` are declarations that do not take arguments; they are to be used as in `{\bfseries text}` (the braces are only to keep the effect local to a group).

Comment: Thx, but I believe, your code doesn't give any benefit to mine in regard of number of lines. In my answer I got rid of initial setting the counter to 1. But couldn't get rid of increase operator.

Comment: @user4035 I added another option to my answer, using a dedicated theorem-like structure.

Comment: @user4035 I don't care much about number of lines of the code, as long as it is syntactically and semantically correct.